# can a thread deploy the signal not immediately?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, multiprocessing, threadpool

Imagine that many threads send signal(maybe created by `pthread_kill`) to a thread.but the thread cant deploy them immediately. Would these signals be lost? How to solve these singals diliveried from other threads?
Any references or experiences? tks for ur consideration.

Comment: sorry, actually I mean, How to store these singals diliveried from other threads?

Comment: The OS will take care to "store" them, if it conforms to POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are "lost". Signals arn't queued[1], they're simply a flag that gets set and cleared. So several signals arriving after the first signal but before the signal is handled have no effect.

The solution is to avoid using unix signals for message passing (and really, for most things), but rather something else , e.g. communicating through memory with the help of mutexes and condition variables.

[1] There are realtime signals, that can be queued, atleast within some limits, and they come with their own set of problems.

Comment: I didnt find flags about signal in structure of [Thread Control Block](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~soumyadeb/projects/mtp/report/node56.html).

Comment: @NickDong, perhaps this kernel does not implement (POSIX) signals.

Answer (score 0):

If the signals are sent to a specific thread and they are currently blocked, they will stay pending in the thread. When and if they are unblocked (e.g. via `pthread_sigmask`) the appropriate signal action will be performed.

PS. Unless they are queued signals (cf. `sigqueue`), the information whether it has been only one of multiple signals will be lost.

Comment: If a thread try to deploy the signal and run action function, do they have to stop their current sequential tasks, or OS would help thread to deploy signals?